# ツール バーの中のドロップダウンリストボックスの表示部分を長くしたい

Tags: emeditor

[image: 図]のように、現在は

[フィルター]１２３４５６７８９０１２３
[検索]１２３４５６７８９０１２３

のように約13文字が表示されているのですが、これを

[フィルター]１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０
[検索]１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０

のように長く表示させることはできますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

レジストリ エディタ (regedit.exe) で、`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\EmSoft\EmEditor v3\Common` キーの中に、以下の `REG_DWORD` 値を設定することにより、ドロップ ダウン リストの幅を変更することができます。

`CWFind`: **検索**ツール バーの**検索**ドロップ ダウン リスト 既定値: 0xc8 (200)
`CWReplace`: **検索**ツール バーの**置換**ドロップ ダウン リスト 既定値: 0xc8 (200)
`CWFilter`: **フィルター** ツール バーの**検索**ドロップ ダウン リスト 既定値: 0xc8 (200)
`CWColumn`: **フィルター** ツール バーの**列**ドロップ ダウン リスト 既定値: 0x7d (125)

参考: [Version 15.5 の新機能](https://jp.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/history/new-in-version-15-5/#other_features)

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\EmSoft\EmEditor v3\Commonの中に CWFindなどの名前が見つかりません。

Comment: 元来、これらの値は存在しないので、新規作成する必要があります。

Comment: 新規作成して10進数の表記で指定しましたら変更できました。ありがとうございました。